# Emacs: Symbol's function definition is void: use-package

Tags: debugging, emacs, package

I'm trying to configuring Emacs on Windows and there is one package "use-package" which I wanna to insert in this on my configuration, but when I press to execute on Emacs show the message "Symbol's function definition is void: use-package"

```
(setq inhibit-startup-message t)

(require 'package)
(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("gnu" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/"))

(package-initialize)


(unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)
  (package-refresh-contents)
  (package-install 'use-package))
```

Sometimes I receive error message "use-package is unavailable."

```
    Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function package-installed-p)
    (package-installed-p (quote use-package))
    (if (package-installed-p (quote use-package)) nil (package-refresh-contents) (package-install (quote use-package)))
    eval((if (package-installed-p (quote use-package)) nil (package-refresh-contents) (package-install (quote use-package))) nil)
    elisp--eval-last-sexp(nil)
    eval-last-sexp(nil)
    funcall-interactively(eval-last-sexp nil)
    call-interactively(eval-last-sexp nil nil)
    command-execute(eval-last-sexp)
```

Comment: I don't think they code you are showing could cause this. Can you obtain a backtrace to see which code path exactly is triggering this message? (If nothing else, the final closing parenthesis is also missing, so this *precise* code doesn't even parse.)

Comment: I forgot to add the last parenthesis on the question.

Answer (score 34):

You should be able to find `use-package` in the list produced with `M-x package-list-packages`. If that is the case, then `(package-install 'use-package)` should succeed: the package is available on MELPA.

To use it, you have to add

```
(require 'use-package)
```

to your .emacs (or equivalent).

Comment: thanks for the help, I believed because of the "https" on the address MELPA which was changed for "http:", the emacs wasn't installing the MELPA package.

Comment: For what it's worth, in Aquamacs (Mac OS Emacs) the command is M-x package-list-packages, perhaps in other variants as well.

Comment: What about if that's not the case (`use-package` is missing)?

Comment: You need to add the MELPA repository to `package-archives`: `(add-list `package-archives   '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/"))` - after restarting Emacs, you should be able to find it in the list.

Comment: When I do `M-x package-list-packages`, I get the error message "Invalid version list `(4 5 -4 414)'". What does this mean?

Comment: You should ask that in a separate question, not in a  comment. When you ask the question, add the backtrace that you will get after you do `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` and do `M-x package-list-packages` again.

Comment: I've posted the question [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/72168/invalid-version-list-4-5-4-414-when-running-m-x-package-list-packages).